# Where is msleep declared?

Tags: c++, header

The source from [here](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/19607-there-any-simple-c-timer-around.html#post236498) says that it is supposed to work on the iPhone.  I have worked with it, but I get 2 errors, saying that msleep() is undeclared.  I have tried to include unistd.h, time.h, and numerous others.  How can I get this to work?  Thanks.

Comment: can I ask if you did the obvious and searched for the text string in your entire system header directory, instead of just guessing a few fields to look into?

Comment: or did you google?   http://nfosolutions.com/doc_link/C/a_doc_lib/libs/basetrf1/msleep.htm

Comment: In fairness that's for AIX - here's the equivalent from BSD with a whole different set of includes: http://www.unix.com/man-page/all/9/msleep/ (Although given Darwin is BSD-based I'd give these a go.)

Answer (score 5):

There is nothing in that linked thread stating that `msleep` is available. The original author, `bagusflyer`, actually implemented their *own* `msleep`, stating:

> Sorry. Maybe I missed something in my code. Here is my msleep:

```
#include <sys/time.h>
void msleep (unsigned int ms) {
    int microsecs;
    struct timeval tv;
    microsecs = ms * 1000;
    tv.tv_sec  = microsecs / 1000000;
    tv.tv_usec = microsecs % 1000000;
    select (0, NULL, NULL, NULL, &tv);  
}
```

However, you should be careful about using that code since I think, from memory, that `select()` is interruptable.

Answer (score 5):

The [`msleep()`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=msleep&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%206.0-RELEASE%20and%20Ports&format=html) is a non-standard artifact from early BSDs, before the [`clock_nanosleep()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_nanosleep.html) and [`nanosleep()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/nanosleep.html) made it into POSIX.

It is unportable. On some systems it is available by default - on others one has to compile the code with `_BSD_SOURCE` define.

iPhone is a distant relative of Mac OS X, which is distant relative of NeXT, which is very distant relative of BSD 4.x. So the function might have stuck in some header/library somewhere, but you shouldn't use it anyway. If memory serves me right, check the `NSThread`'s `sleepForTimeInterval:` static method.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use usleep(). It is also in unistd.h.