# msleep() produces inaccurate sleep intervals QT

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

There is a bigger project where packets have to be sent with a delay after each other, plus the sleep amount is pretty slim, about 1ms. But `msleep()` proceeds to a very random and in accurate result.

Say in a loop of 10 times with `msleep(1)` on each loop, we expected a elapsed time of 10.5 ms while received from 9ms (which should be impossible) to 33ms.

```
   QElapsedTimer time;
   time.start();

  while(f<11){
      qDebug("looping...");
      f++;
      msleep(1); //or msleep(10) produces same result.
  }
      qDebug() << time.elapsed();
```

Now in the snippet above we expect a period of 10ms while receive from 165ms to 175ms, the same result with `msleep(10)` which should certainly not happen.

Now considering that I need stops around 1ms, any help is appreciated.

PS. I googled a lot but only came into `beginTimePeriod()` which im not sure is QT compatible and how its usable

Comment: `beginTimePeriod` is a global OS function that affects all running programs on the OS. Basically, it sets interval in milliseconds in which the OS notifies/triggers programs. Downside of it being lower is increased energy consumption. I presume QT just forwards the sleep request to OS. I don't see it working in any other way.

Comment: @ALX23z Also increases overhead.  Every pass through the scheduler costs CPU cycles.  _I presume QT just forwards the sleep request to OS. I don't see it working in any other way._ Me neither.

Comment: @PaulSanders so you guys think there is no resolution to this?

Comment: It's unlikely.  A general purpose OS is not set up for precision timing like this.

Comment: On Windows you can use `beginTimePeriod` and get `1ms` resolution on all sleeps but there are no cross-platform solutions. Linux doesn't have functionality to address the issue. Though, I heard there is some work done in this direction.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know on which platform you are but nowadays strange results may appear.

Unloaded computer will perform worse than loaded ones because in this case only low power/performance cores are active, or your high power cores fell asleep and must be woken.

We could also put in doubt the results given by time.elapsed() but let's assume it is correct.

By looking at some nanosleep( ... ) documentation ( [where is msleep() declared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3548917/3972710) ) we are invited to use pthread condition variables.

On an not loaded at all Mac mini M1 a single cv.wait_until(...) and a QThread::msleep(10u) perform the same @ 12 ms reported by time.elapsed()

Doing like in your example a 10 times iterations cv.wait_until(...) is reported @ 9ms ( what you saw also on your system )

QThread::msleep(100u) is reported @ 125 ms whereas iterative cv.wait_until(...) is reported @ 99 ms

My MCVE just to save the idea (My Qt is very rusty I used std condition variables) :

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include <QElapsedTimer>
#include <QThread>

#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>

std::condition_variable cv;
std::mutex cv_m;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QElapsedTimer time;
    time.start();
    unsigned int tempo = 10u;

    //the clock with the shortest tick period available
    auto beginning = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    for (unsigned int k=0;k<tempo;k++) {
#if 1
        auto timepoint = beginning + std::chrono::milliseconds(k);
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lk(cv_m);
        while( std::cv_status::timeout  != cv.wait_until(lk,timepoint )){}
#else
        QThread::msleep(1u);
#endif
    }
    qDebug() << time.elapsed();

    return a.exec();
}
```